# Log scale (x axis) histogram

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram

what I need is a histogram with X axis displayed on a log scale. However, I still want every bar in a histogram to be of the same width.

Whatever, I came up with (or upon) display bars with higher values as narrower ones (they are of the same width on ordinary scale and not on log scale).

Here is what I am doing now:

```
edges = 10.^(c_min:0.1:c_max); 
h = histc(data, edges);
bar(edges, h); set(gca, 'Xscale', 'log');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your bars should be evenly spaced, you can plot them with x-values 1,2,.. and then change the axis labels.

```
edges = 10.^(c_min:0.1:c_max); 
h = histc(data, edges);

centers = sqrt(edges(1:end-1).*edges(2:end));

bar(h)

%# fix the x-labels, x-axis extents
xlim([0.5,length(centers)+0.5])
set(gca,'xticklabel',num2str(centers(:),'%5.2f'))
```

Comment: Nice and simple approach, do you perhaps know if there a way to print numbers such as 10^12 nicely?

Comment: @gintas: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881492/select-a-different-base-for-a-logarithmic-plot-in-matlab) for how to plot nicely-formatted tick labels.

Comment: you'd have problems when zooming/panning, otherwise, this is OK

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: you're right. However, for bar graphs, at least I don't usually zoom and pan.

Answer (score 1):

Use `patch` instead of `bar`:

```
figure, hold on
edges = 10.^(c_min:0.1:c_max);
h = histc(data, edges);

for ii = 1:numel(edges)-1    
    patch(...
        [edges(ii) edges(ii) edges(ii+1) edges(ii+1)], ...
        [0 h(ii) h(ii) 0],...
        'b');
end
```

Although this particular code does not do what you want, that is a problem with the definition of `edges` rather than the methodology, so you'd have to fiddle a bit with the `edges` (perhaps re-define them for the `patch`)