# Octave: Log plot with arbitrary log base automatically

Tags: plot, gnuplot, octave

I want to plot some data in log scale but can't find an option to automatically change the base of the log scale.

```
x = 1:100;
y = 2 .^ x;

semilogy(x, y);
```

gives me

[image]

I have been able to manually change the y ticks.

```
x = 1:100;
y = 2 .^ x;

semilogy(x, y);
set(gca, 'ytick', 2 .^ (0:20:100));
set(gca, 'yticklabel', {'2^{0}' '2^{20}' '2^{40}' '2^{60}' '2^{80}' '2^{100}'});
```

gives me

[image: Plot with log base 2 scale]

I am satisfied by the plot I get, but just out of curiosity, is there an option to automatically change the log base of the log scale?

Comment: I don't know why you added the `gnuplot` tag. With gnuplot, you can just use `set logscale x 2` to switch to use base of 2.

Comment: @Christoph: I added it because I thought the gnuplot community might also know a way to do it in Octave

Comment: Ok, just wanted to know if an answer using plain gnuplot would also be acceptable. I had a look at `semilogx.m`, which uses `set(gca, 'xscale', 'log')`, but the only options for `xscale` are `linear` and `log`. So I guess you must either stick with the manual ticks, or use gnuplot directly.  We'll see :)

Answer (score 0):

As Christoph said there is no option for that in octave or matlab. You may automate a little bit the process, and ensure consistency between ticks positions and labels, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881492/select-a-different-base-for-a-logarithmic-plot-in-matlab).

For instance

```
x = 1:100;
y = 2 .^ x;

semilogy(x, y);
base = 2;
tick_exponents = 0:20:100;
set(gca, 'ytick', base .^ tick_exponents);
format_string = sprintf('%d^{%%d}', base);
tick_labels = num2str(tick_exponents(:), format_string)
set(gca, 'yticklabel', tick_labels);
```

which yields
[image]