# Plotting on a log base 2 scale

Tags: matlab

Following the recommendation in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881492/select-a-different-base-for-a-logarithmic-plot-in-matlab), I tried to plot the log2 values of my data and also display the tick labels on the horizontal and vertical axes as a power of 2. But I am not getting the desired tick labels along either axes. On both axes, I would have liked the tick labels to be displayed as integer powers of 2, i.e., on the x-axis: 3 and 4, on the y-axis: 0, -1, -2, -3, -4 and -5. Here is my code:

```
x = [ 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 ]
Tcomm = [ 0.0357, 0.0515, 0.0745, 0.0956, 0.122, 0.1596, 0.2005, 0.2443, 0.2873, 0.3752, 0.4148, 0.5102, 0.5882 ]
plot(log2(x), log2(Tcomm), 'ko')
set(gca, 'XTickLabel',[])                      %# suppress current x-labels
xlim([log2(8),log2(16)])
xt = get(gca, 'XTick');
yl = get(gca, 'YLim');
str = cellstr( num2str(xt(:),'2^{%d}') );      %# format x-ticks as 2^{xx}
hTxt = text(xt, yl(ones(size(xt))), str, ...   %# create text at same locations
'Interpreter','tex', ...                   %# specify tex interpreter
'VerticalAlignment','top', ...             %# v-align to be underneath
'HorizontalAlignment','center');           %# h-aligh to be centered

xlabel('N');
ylim([log2(0.0357), log2(0.58825)])
set(gca, 'YTickLabel',[])
xt = get(gca, 'YTick');
yl = get(gca, 'XLim');
str = cellstr( num2str(xt(:),'2^{%d}') );      %# format x-ticks as 2^{xx}
hTxt = text(xt, yl(ones(size(xt))), str, ...   %# create text at same locations
'Interpreter','tex', ...                   %# specify tex interpreter
'VerticalAlignment','middle', ...             %# v-align to be underneath
'HorizontalAlignment','right');           %# h-aligh to be centered

ylabel('CommunicationTime');
title('(a)');
```

Comment: You only have two integer powers of 2 in your `x` data, 8 and 16.

Comment: What are your desired tick labels? `xt` contains values with a `.5` but you *attempt* to print integers with `%d`.

Comment: Right, on the x axis, just 3 and 4. On the y-axis: 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5

Answer (score 0):

For the Y-axis part, in the text command, just interchange the first and second values:

```
xlabel('N');
ylim([log2(0.0357), log2(0.58825)])
set(gca, 'YTickLabel',[])
xt = get(gca, 'YTick');
yl = get(gca, 'XLim');
str = cellstr( num2str(xt(:),'2^{%d}') );      %# format x-ticks as 2^{xx}
hTxt = text( yl(ones(size(xt))),xt, str, ...   %# create text at same locations
'Interpreter','tex', ...                   %# specify tex interpreter
'VerticalAlignment','middle', ...             %# v-align to be underneath
'HorizontalAlignment','right');           %# h-aligh to be centered
```